# How to connect using menubar in pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt5

I want to open a picture when I click the menu, but I don't know how
I want to be able to output the specified image file when clicking the submenu.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMenu, QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon,QAction,*

class Example(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.initUI()
  
  def initUI(self):
      menubar= self.menubar()
      self.filemenu = menubar.addmenu('a')
      x= QMenu('b',self)
      y= QMenu('c',self)
      self.filemenu.addmenu(y)
      self.x1 =QAction('d',self)
      x.addMenu(self.x1)
      self.x1.triggered.connect(self.fileopen)

  def fileopen(self):
      qpixmapvar=QPixmap()
      qpixmapvar.load("C:\\desktop\\A.png")
      self.label.setPixmap(qPixmapvar)
      self.label.resize(qPixmapvar.width(), qPixmapvar.height())

  
if__name__ =='__main__':
 app= Qapplication(sys.argv)
 ex = Example()
 sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: i suggest you replace Qapplication by `QApplication`  ; and if__name__ == '__main__': by `if __name__ == '__main__':`  also  import `QMenuBar` ; QAction belong to QWidgets

Comment: You forgot to create  `QLabel` and `QMenuBar`

Comment: ex = Example() cannot display the App thre is no `ex.show()` or `self.show()` anywhere

Comment: Please try to present a better formulation (precision) of your question; because a **Menu** is different from a **submenu**.  Do you want to click on the Menu itseft or its drop down items (submenus)